# building tests that deal with redis and cache_method decorator

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, redis

So I'm trying to build some tests for a project using redis but I have two methods giving me trouble.

both methods use the `@cache_method()` decorator and will spit out a failure report akin to `AssertionError: [] != []` or `AsserionError: [<ObjectName: instance_name>] != [<ObjectName: instance_name>]`.  The tests are both something along the line of:

```
self.assertEquals(self.ObjectName.Method(), ObjectName.objects.none())
```

or

```
self.assertEquals(self.ObjectName.Method(), ObjectName.objects.filter(...))
```

If I use something like `self.assertEquals(type(), type())` the test passes so I'm at a complete loss.

my test class looks like this:

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.reset_pool()
        self.cache = self.get_cache()
        self.cache.clear()

        ... setup a bunch of self.Object instances for the actual tests ...

    def reset_pool(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'cache'):
            self.cache._client.connection_pool.disconnect()

    def get_cache(self, backend=None):
        if VERSION[0] == 1 and VERSION[1] < 3:
            cache = get_cache(backend or 'redis_cache.cache://127.0.0.1:6379?db=15')
        elif VERSION[0] == 1 and VERSION[1] >= 3:
            cache = get_cache(backend or 'default')
        return cache
```

How can I get these tests to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Does `self.ObjectName.Method()` return a QuerySet? If not I'd suspect that is your problem. `ObjectName.objects.filter(...)` will return a QuerySet. If your method returns anything else, then naturally the assert will fail.

More specifically `ObjectName.objects.none()` will return an django.db.models.query.EmtpyQuerySet and `filter()` will return either a `django.db.models.query.EmptyQuerySet` or a `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` depending on what, if anything, matches the filter.

So it seems somewhere you are trying to compare an `ObjectName.method()` that is either:
  a) not returning a QuerySet but something different
    -or-
  b) is returning QuerySet when an EmptyQuerySet is expected (such as when none() is called), or vice-versa.

Since we don't know what `ObjectName.method()` is or what it returns, you'll need to look into that/those method(s) to see what it is returning and possibly why.

I hope that points you in the right direction.